# Is it ever appropriate to give guidelines or hints instead of a straightforward answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

For one of my earliest answers on Stack Overflow, instead of simply providing a code sample that would explicitly solve the OP's problem, I decided to give a sort of ["non-answer" amounting to "do your own work"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541279/1858225) (and then [explicitly acknowledged in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541243/return-a-list-with-every-duplicate-value-in-python/14541279?noredirect=1#comment20281745_14541279) that this was my intent).

In retrospect, I realize that my answer didn't really do much to improve Stack Overflow as a reference site for potential future viewers of the question; but then again, neither did the question. Also, I realized that someone else would probably just post a code answer, effectively making my refusal to answer irrelevant, which is exactly what happened.

I still, however, can see some potential value in "answering" questions in a way that doesn't exactly give the OP exactly what they were hoping for. In the case above, I was hoping to encourage the OP to pursue some of *their own ideas* before potentially coming back and asking a better question. Of course, this didn't happen (note that this question was asked by one of those people who register an account just to get help on a single problem). But I was young and optimistic back then. (Cough.)

There's another example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177827/218334). In this case, as I explained in my answer, the post in question is both humorous (which I think is a very good thing) and (in my opinion) helpful. And I would even say that there's some value in having "answers" that *allow readers to figure out the complete answer for themselves by giving them just enough help to get started.* And if a particular reader wants the gold-paved high road to The Correct Answer, then they can simply check out the other answers.

In short, I think there's value in answers that don't explicitly answer the question asked, even (or perhaps especially) if these answers are (probably) doomed never to be the highest-rated or accepted answer for a given question. So I plan to continue giving and up-voting such answers when it seems appropriate to me to do so.

My question is, is this a violation of the rules and/or goals of this community? Or is it, as I think, well in keeping with the spirit of Stack Overflow?

---

EDIT: Part of the reason I think these types of answers are acceptable is that they're independent from the other answers to the same question. Failing to answer straightforwardly doesn't prevent others from doing so, and ultimately the answer that is accepted (and, probably, highest-rated) will almost certainly be a fairly straightforward (if in-depth) answer. I think both types of answers add value to the site; it makes sense to me to let more straightforward answers rise to the top naturally rather than explicitly deleting all answers that don't *quite* answer the question.

For example: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236278/1858225) made me smile, but it's obviously never going to become more prominent than the (fantastic) accepted answer. I think it's good that both answers exist.

Comment: I believe the comment saying `This is a comment, not an answer` is accurate. I do this too, when I want to point someone in the right direction - but since it _isn't_ an answer, I don't make it an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think if I gave that answer today, I might give it as a comment. Even so, I still kind of think that "do your own work" is a valid *answer* to some questions.

Comment: Can you give an example where `Do your own work` answers the question?

Comment: I'd say that your answer didn't really give any guidelines or hints. It just said "that looks fine, keep trying". I often post partial answers when I smell homework, but I always try to make sure that my answer is actually providing some useful information even if I leave some parts as an "excercise for the reader".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Giving hints is OK. Many questions cannot be reasonably answered with code, you can instead say "do this, then do this, then do this"

Giving hints *this* thiny isn't:

> Making a new list that contains duplicates sounds like a good start to me. This looks like a homework problem, so just start coding and see what happens; don't rely on StackOverflow to answer questions for you.

2/3rd of your answer is the homework dislaimer. You have one measly hint, which really makes it not an answer, just a comment.

If your hint was a paragraph or two long, it would be fine.

In such cases, it is better to leave a comment and flag the question as "too localized" (it was pretty localized IMO). Questions that don't have much scope for detailed hints generally  have other problems. Don't answer these.

Comment: I agree that my "answer" could scarcely even be called a "hint"; personally, I think it's a bit unfortunate that by drawing attention to it here, I caused it to get deleted (since in a way I'm being punished for making a good-faith effort to add to the discussion about the needs/wants/goals of the community), but I suppose that's for the best. I do, however, still disagree with the deletion of the answer to the "-->" question.

Answer (score 13):

One of the reasons I was so attracted to Stack Overflow at least initially was the way it satisfied my persistent, somewhat secret desire to *quit this crazy industry and just teach*. I'm fairly confident in saying that I'm not the only one to use the site as a vent for that desire.

I'm sure you're familiar with the old *teach a man to fish ...* adage, to expand that metaphor a bit think of a fishing school, and a fish market. When you're hungry both have value, the urgency surrounding your need to know is what really dictates which option you choose.

The best answers I've ever seen on the site were both the market and the school. They hand someone a fish to solve their immediate need, and then they go on to do something awesome; *they entice the knowledge seeker to return and figure out how you caught that fish* by providing substantial background into how you came up with the answer that you did.

One of the biggest reasons I pushed so hard to [deprecate the homework tag on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) is that 'good' answers were expected to not directly answer the question - directly contradicting answers to other questions where the tag was not applied.

Use your discretion, just do your best to tailor your answer to what the question author really needs, while ensuring that the answer is also extremely helpful to someone finding your post while frantically searching for something an hour before a deadline. That's really what defines our brand - if you need to know something and see a Stack Exchange site in your results, you can have a high expectation that it's game over - you'll get what you need.

Comment: "tailor your answer to what the question author really needs" I've been questioning if that is necessary or worth the time anymore. I've had a lot of askers recently accepting answers that completely miss the point, leaving me to think that I somehow am the one who's missing the point when I just don't see how I could have.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I try to answer as if I was explaining it to a _group_ that perhaps has the same question, misconception or what not. I've seen what you describe, I think it varies by tag. I will say it's not you that missed the point, some people just favor the path of least resistance. Still, no reason to stop trying to get to the crux of the question - it will definitely help others.

Comment: My one reservation about this answer is that it seems to me that the *existence* of answers that don't straightforwardly provide "the fish" doesn't in any way threaten the answers that **do** just jump straight to the point. Yes, answers that are more complete should score higher and be accepted; but do we need to *eradicate* answers that are less complete and possibly more interesting in their own way?